# Applying the Martingale central limit theorem to the score process of an autoregressive model

Tags: econometrics, time-series, martingales, probability

This question is a natural continuation of the following question: [How do I construct the score process of a Markov model and verify that it is a Martingale?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/how-do-i-construct-the-score-process-of-a-markov-model-and-verify-that-it-is-a-m) In this problem, we set up as follows:

> Consider the following autoregressive model:
>   $$
> X_{t+1} = \alpha_0 + \beta_0 (X_t - \alpha_0) + W_{t+1},
> $$
>   where $-1 < \beta_0 < 1$ and $W_{t+1}$ is distributed as a normal with mean zero and variance one.

The question constructs a log-likelihood process and the associated score process:

> $$
> s_t(\theta \mid \textbf X) =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  (1 - \beta_0) \sum_{j=1}^t W_j \\
>  \sum_{j=1}^t W_j (X_{j-1} - \alpha_0)
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$

After verifying that the score process is a Martingale, a natural follow is to compute
the covariance matrix for a central limit approximation for this process and find the inverse of the matrix. How would I do this? Also, how would I interpret the one-one component of the inverse?

After looking at the Wikipedia article on the [Martingale central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_central_limit_theorem), it seems like this may be a little difficult given that the statement of the theorem requires the difference sequence to be uniformly bounded. Am I missing something or is there a generalization that I'm missing?